# Sort x-axis for proportional stacked barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I have a data set like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  sample = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s4", "s5", "S5", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S8", "S8", "S9", "S9", "S9"),
  ploidy = c(3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4),
  freq = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 1.0, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8)
)
```

It may not be difficult to generate stacked barplot like this:

[image]

But i need to make it more elegant, it would be perfect if i can sort the x-axis based on the decreasing order of proportion of ploidy 4 for each sample. for the samples have no ploidy 4, just order them alphabetically.

Highly appreciate if anyone could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arrange` and `forcats::fct_inorder` to set the order you want

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(perc = freq/sum(freq), .by = sample) %>% 
  arrange(desc(ploidy), desc(perc)) %>% 
  mutate(sample = forcats::fct_inorder(sample)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample, y = perc)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(ploidy)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Appreciate, my friend! And your code is very concise and elegant! Thank you for your timely help!